# WebPushError - Received unexpected response code BadJwtToken

Tags: ios, web-push

I am trying to send a web push notification to my ios device. The code I have with teh vapid ID works perfectly for desktop and on android devices when I send the FCM token.

The issue happens when I get the web.push.app.com URL. Firebase says it can send it. Is there something I need to do on APPLEs side to authenticate these pushes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my subject from

"subject": "**mailto: dev_admin@momint.so**"

to

"subject": "**mailto:dev_admin@momint.so**"